# Recursively processing a nested list in scheme to search for an atom

Tags: list, recursion, scheme

My goal is to recursively iterate through any given list and count how many times a given atom appears in the list. I keep getting an error involving procedures. Currently my code looks like this:

```
(define (count atom x)
(cond
    ((null? x) 0)
    ((not (list? (car x)))
        (cond
            ((eqv? (car x) atom) (+ 1 (count(atom (cdr x)))))
            (else(+ 0 (count atom (cdr x))))))
    (else(+ (count atom (cdr x)) (count atom (car x))))))

(display(count 1 '(1 3)))
```

I attempt to check if the first element is not a nested list using car. If it is not, I compare it to the atom. If it equals the atom, I recurse, adding 1 to the return value, otherwise I recurse while adding 0. If the first element of the list is indeed a nested list, then I recursively search it using cdr and car.

To make my question more clear, why am I getting this procedure error? Am I close to a final solution?

Comment: You have forgot to ask a question, but I guess you are having a "not a procedure" problem?

Comment: Sorry! Yes that was my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your `cond` you can flatten the two into one by switching the last two:

```scm
(define (count atom x)
  (cond
    ((null? x) 0)
    ((list? (car x)) (+ (count atom (cdr x)) (count atom (car x))))
    ((eqv? (car x) atom) (+ 1 (count (atom (cdr x)))))
    (else (+ 0 (count atom (cdr x))))))
```

In the second to last term you are trying to call your element as if it was a procedure `(atom (cdr x))` and it's an argument to `count` which takes two. Removing the extra parenthesis I cannot find any problems with this:

```scm
(define (count atom x)
  (cond
    ((null? x) 0)
    ((list? (car x)) (+ (count atom (cdr x)) (count atom (car x))))
    ((eqv? (car x) atom) (+ 1 (count atom (cdr x)))) ; changes this
    (else (+ 0 (count atom (cdr x))))))
```

Comment: Ah thanks a whole lot! I'm happy to see I wasn't too far off, and this fix seems to be working. Flattening the two conds certainly does help the readability! Also I read over my code quite a bit but I still wasn't able to catch that argument error, so thanks for that too!